# Change dynamic div heights on fix layout without JS?

Tags: html, css

So I have a layout and I have some question about it. I am not sure it is possible, but I give it a try!

As you can see from the attached image, in nutshell, my problem is how to make red and blue divs to have scrollbars and proper heights when they needed WITHOUT JAVASCRIPT. (With JS it is fine, but I have to discover if it can be done without it.)
So when the resolution is smaller red and blue divs are smaller too, with scrollbars.
Basically these two divs' heights are the only changeable things.

So is it possible with pure CSS, or SASS, or anything? Pure HTML and CSS could work like this?
Interested in any solution.
Thank you!

Here is the mockup for it, thus we can play with it.

[jsfiddle](http://tinyurl.com/kch832c)

Here is the layout plan and some information:
[layout png http://kepfeltoltes.hu/140730/muse_layout_stack_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png](http://kepfeltoltes.hu/140730/muse_layout_stack_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png)

Comment: Should be possible with css but without seeing your code, it is hard to provide any solutions

Comment: Thanks for answering. Jsfiddle added for the mockup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright, I managed to reach something very close I want! Maybe this is the end with pure css.
Here it is:
http://jsfiddle.net/r42EQ/

The only week point is that I have to specify the top value of left and right content:

```
.leftCont { top: 80px; background: #bf828c; }
.rightCont { top: 100px; background: #90a6ba; }
```

Is there a way to make it even better to avoid these must-given top values?
I really thank you!